# Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, path

I already searched for this answer and I keep on seeing change your "PATH" but I don't know how to go about doing that. I'm just trying to run this simple code:

```
package eclipsePackage;

public class TutorialClass {


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me thoroughly please. I'm using eclipse and java jre1.8.0_40

Comment: How are you compiling/executing the java class?

Comment: Google `java set path` first result. This question is for google not stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you have the "build automatically" option not set in Eclipse so when you try to launch your app nothing has been compiled

Comment: Eh eh...remote debugging :) Please accept my answer above ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything from the way your code is laid out.  Move your java class (without the  package statement) into a folder on your C:drive and try running it from the command line. If it works there, then there's probably an issue with your ide.  If that's the case,  reinstall your ide or revert to the default settings.